# Preventing drop caps from overlapping next paragraph

Tags: drop-cap, lettrine

Using the `lettrine` package, big drop caps can sometimes overlap next paragraphs, as show here:

[image: overlap]

How can I do it so that following paragraphs are built around the lettrine instead of overlapping it?

Comment: What does your lettrine definition for this typesetting look like?

Comment: Don't start a new paragraph: `\\\indent`.

Comment: You can do some tricks with redefining `\par` using `\prevgraf` (there is a code somewhere in The TeXbook, but I don't have it at home).  Note that this might not be robust with respect to `itemize` or other atypical things.

If you don't have access to The TeXbook, just write a comment here and I will post working code tomorrow.

Comment: Ok egreg, your trick does it (although I'd like something cleaner if possible).

Comment: @mbork **lettrine** already uses `\parshape`, so it's not compatible with `list` based environments. The code might be something like `{\par\xdef\kpd{\the\prevgraf}}\everypar={\prevgraf\kpd\everypar{}`, perhaps with some other code to keep the previous contents of `\everypar`. I'd say that `\\\indent` is more economic.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of;).  Hopefully wrapping text around figures will work robustly in LaTeX3...

Solution with `\\\indent` is *very* nice, I'll remember it (I need wrapping from time to time, too).

Comment: @Raphink What fonts are you using? They look great.

Comment: @JohnReed: This font is EB Garamond, and yes it's great. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24719/951 for what this font can achieve (essentially the result of this question).

Comment: @Raphink That is truly impressive. Also, thanks for the font name.

Comment: @JohnReed: You're welcome. You can find the latest version of EB Garamond on https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond. It is best used as OTF with `fontspec`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@egreg's suggestion works fine. So since I already had a command to typeset for each paragraph (`\bverse`), I made a new command (`\bversenopar`) and didn't skip a line:

```
\newcounter{verse}                                                              
\newcommand{\bverse}{%                                                          
  \addtocounter{verse}{1}                                                       
  \par\theverse~                                                                
}                                                                               

\newcommand{\bversenopar}{%                                                     
   \addtocounter{verse}{1}\\\indent\theverse~                                   
}
```

And it works fine:

[image: no overlap]

Comment: Books like this need a wide amount of manual intervention.

Comment: Yes indeed, but it's fun :-) I'm trying to get as close as possible to a 1564 French Bible.